# IsNullOrEmpty attribute

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

In HTML exists

> required

attribute, which force user to enter some date before submit. But user can type only spaces. Is there attribute which check is typed content is whitespace before postback. In need attibute which works similar to string.IsNullOrWhitespace in c#.

Comment: You should have a look at the HTML5 attribute `pattern` for inputs. You can pass it a validation regex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to get the Regex right, but the following creates a rule to only select if there's no whitespace:

```
<input type="text" pattern=".\S*" />
```

As @Paul S. noted, this isn't checking the first character, so the following will do that:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^.\S*" />
```

Also, this does indeed only work in HTML5 browsers, but since the question contained `required`, I'm assuming there if is some fallback kept in mind.

Comment: This isn't checking the first character, `/^.\S*$/.test(' foo'); // true`

Comment: @PaulS. True, sorry, I am not the most well-versed in regex. Thanks for that. Your answer is a lot more comprehensive though.

Answer (score 1):

Using the *pattern* attribute, you can make it accept only spaces

```html
<form action="?" method="post"> <!-- required for snippet -->
  <input type="text" required pattern="\s*"/>
</form>
```

However, please note that *required* prevents the submission of empty input (i.e. your *"null"*), so to permit that remove *required* so that *pattern* is doing the requirement checking

```html
<form action="?" method="post"> <!-- required for snippet -->
  <input type="text" pattern="\s*"/>
</form>
```

Lastly, still perform validation on the server as you can never assume a client is a safe source, or conversely, always assume the client is trying to hack you

---

If you can't assume *HTML 5* support, you can shim the behaviour using *JavaScript*, which would look something like this for *required*

```
if(!('required' in document.createElement('input'))) {
    window.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        var form = e.target, 
            inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input'),
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i)
            if (inputs[i].getAttribute('required'))
                if (!inputs[i].value)
                    e.preventDefault(); // + warn?
    });
}
```

and for *pattern*

```
if(!('pattern' in document.createElement('input'))) {
    window.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        var form = e.target, 
            inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input'),
            i,
            re;
        for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i)
            if (re = inputs[i].getAttribute('pattern')) {
                re = new RegExp('^' + re + '$');
                if (!re.test(inputs[i].value))
                    e.preventDefault(); // + warn?
            }
    });
}
```

You could also set *useCapture* to `true` for the listener to skip ahead in the queue of handlers, letting you prevent the event reaching other handlers in the case of submission prevented

Answer (score 0):

```js
<
```

```html
<form onsubmit="alert('Submitted.');return false;">            <input type="text" required="" pattern="(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))" value="" name="dates_pattern2" id="dates_pattern2" list="dates_pattern2_datalist" placeholder="Try it out." autocomplete="off">            <input type="submit" value="»">            <datalist id="dates_pattern2_datalist">            </datalist>          </form>
```